# Youtube API : CommentThreads.list how to get last comments?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

By reading the docs : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list when listing the commenthreads related to a channel, by default, I get the last 20 comment threads ordered by "time". IMHO this is not accurate : is it the time of creation or update or ... ?

While using the API, I found that it was the last 20 *created* threads. Am I right ?

Considering that, I would like to get the last 20 *updated* threads. Is it possible ? (to get the last comments on this channel which are not necessarily part of the last comment threads)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't think this is possible straight from the API. [Comments.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) will give you the comments under a certain commentThread but it won't tell you which is the latest. You'll have to work your own implementation on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I thought. I will work on something